How to make all child processes share the same file descriptor in C after fork()?
I'm trying to fork multiple child processes in C, and I want all of them to share the same file descriptor.
AS far as i understand it, each child gets a copy of the parent's file descriptors. But when a file descriptor changes somewhere after forking the first child, the later children will see the updated file descriptor, but the first child won’t.
How can I make sure all children share the same file descriptor and see the same updates?
PS: Sorry if my code sucks, I'm new to C and a student who's trying his best.
PS2: The h_functions are provided by the professor to help with error validation.
void server_app(char *service)
{
    // Error handling done by the fon.c library / Thank you Professor !
    int socketFD = h_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);

    struct sockaddr_in *p_sock_addr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    // calling the adr_socket to populate p_sock_addr for us
    // NULL here refers to 0.0.0.0,
    //      so will be listening to all up coming request no matter the IP addresses
    adr_socket(service, NULL, SOCK_STREAM, &p_sock_addr);

    // binding local address to a socket with a specific
    //      local IP address (0.0.0.0 in this case) and port number
    h_bind(socketFD, p_sock_addr);

    // listening to upcoming requests
    // 1000 requetes maximum dans la file d'attente
    // handling a maximum of 50 clients at the same time
    h_listen(socketFD, 1000);
    int *connectedSockets = (int *)mmap(
            NULL, MAX_CLIENTS * sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    int *clientsCount = (int *)mmap(
            NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

WAITING:
    // waiting for connection
    printf("====================================================\n");
    printf("===== WAITING FOR CONNECTION =====");
    // accepte the connection
    int new_socket = h_accept(socketFD, p_sock_addr);
    connectedSockets[*clientsCount] = new_socket;
    (*clientsCount)++;

    // fork the program if accepting a new request
    pid_t p = fork();

    while (true)
    {
        // handle the request only if received one and created a new thread
        if (p < 0)
        {
            perror("fork fail");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (p > 0)
        {
            printf("I'm The Parent. %d\n", p);
            goto WAITING;
        }
        if (p == 0)
        {
            getpid();
            char *request = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
            h_reads(new_socket, request, 1024);
            printf("====================================================\n");
            printf("Client : %s\n", request);
            printf("====================================================\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < *clientsCount; i++)
                printf("connectedSockets[%d] = %d;\n", i, connectedSockets[i]);

            //  send the client's message to all other clients except the owner
            for (int i = 0; i < *clientsCount; i++)
            {
                if (connectedSockets[i] != new_socket)
                {
                    h_writes(connectedSockets[i], request, strlen(request));
                }
            }

            printf("clients Count : %d\n", *clientsCount);
            free(request);
        }

        // close the connection
        // h_close(new_socket);
    }
}

I’ve tried using fork() but I'm not sure how to make sure all children share the same file descriptor and see the same updates.
Update :
SO I ended up using multithreading to handle blocking code and still have access to the same resources as the main thread. This approach solved the issue I was facing.
I spent a lot of time looking for a solution and I hope it can help someone else someday.

"How can I make sure all children share the same file descriptor and see the same updates?" - you can't. As you already realized yourself, the cloning will be done at time of fork, so any changes afterwards will not be reflected in the existing child. Instead of trying to solve the problem Y ("want all of them to share the same file descriptor.") it might be better to rethink your original (and unknown to us) problem X and find a different approach - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

This question is similar to: Portable way to pass file descriptor between different processes. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think there is too much missing code.  That makes it difficult for us to help you — we can't compile your code.  We don't know what functions such as h_writes() actually do.  We can guess, but we don't like to guess because we frequently guess wrong.  Please provide an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example — the same idea by a different name).  Note "M is for Minimal".

If you need to share updates of your data between instances, maybe you could use threads instead of processes?

Thank you all for the help, I really appreciate the community. As @Gerhardh mentioned, I ended up using multithreading to handle blocking code and have access to the same resources as the main thread. This approach solved the issue I was facing.
Thanks again for all the advice and support! Have a good day, gentlemen.
